# Conditionally compiled code in a shared embedded framework

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project with two separate targets, we'll all them TargetA and TargetB (with different bundle id's etc). They both need to reference an embedded framework we'll call SharedCode. This code has to be in an embedded framework, because in TargetA, it's shared between that target an an extension. But I need to have SharedCode be slightly different between TargetA and TargetB, so I would like to set a Active Compilation Condition flag called FEATURE_1, but only for TargetA. It does not seem that Active Compilation Condition flags are transitive - I cannot set the FEATURE_1 flag for TargetA but not TargetB. Is there another way to accomplish this? I thought of duplicated my embedded framework and setting the flags differently there - but I can't have two targets with the same name, and changing the name leads to a nightmare when I try to import the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by duplicating the SharedCode embedded framework target, creating SharedCodeA and SharedCodeB targets. I then went to Build Settings and overrode the Product Name to "SharedCode" (so that it was no longer $(TARGET_NAME) ) for each of SharedCodeA and SharedCodeB targets. The bundle ID for both remained "com.mycompany.SharedCode". This enabled me to continue to use "import SharedCode" in TargetA and TargetB apps.